# Connect to websocket server from Python script?

Tags: python, websocket

I have the below websocket server taking connections from web clients, and broadcasting data to all of the clients when certain keys are pressed on any of the clients.  Everything is working just fine in that sector.  I have two external Python applications doing various things on the server, however, and I need the websocket server to respond to their activities, as well.  How can I connect to the websocket server from those applications, or is it even possible?

websocket server:

```
class Control(WebSocket):
    def handle(self):
        if self.data == "Left":
            Return = update.leftArrow()
            ClassValues = read_Class()
            LineValue = read_Line()
            message = "Line " + str(ClassValues[Return[1]][LineValue[Return[1]]])
        elif self.data == "Right":
            Return = update.rightArrow()
            LineValue = read_Line()
            message = "Line " + str(ClassValues[Return[1]][LineValue[Return[1]]])
        elif self.data == "Up":
            Return = update.upArrow()
            message = "Control " + str(Return[1])
        elif self.data == "Down":
            Return = update.downArrow()
            message = "Control " + str(Return[1])
        else:
            Return = [False, 0]
        if Return[0]:
            for client in self.server.connections.itervalues():
                client.sendMessage(message)

server = WebSocketServer('', 8000, Control)
server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on new-dev-123's input, I have the following solutions:

Python < 3.6

```
import asyncio
import websockets

if TestCondition:
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(SendMessage(message))

@asyncio.coroutine
def SendMessage(message):
    websocket = yield from websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8000')
    try:
        yield from websocket.send(message)
    finally:
        yield from websocket.close()
```

Python >= 3.6:

```
import websockets, asyncio

async def Forward(message):
        url = 'ws://localhost:8000'
        async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
                await websocket.send(message)
def xmit_Loop(message):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(Forward(message))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the [websockets module](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to connect to your websocket. I think the documentation available on that page is better than any explanation I could give here. It's also pretty simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will listen to the server's messages and print them to the client's screen.

```bash
pip install websockets
```

```py
import asyncio
import websockets


async def handler(websocket):
    while True:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        print(message)


async def main():
    url = "ws://localhost:8181"
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        await handler(ws)
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```